# Pausing and resuming an observable stream, please suggest better options

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

I have a requirement to listen to a stream of items from an observable. When certain conditions arise an asynchronous task will be performed on the item and the component will be 'busy' until this completes. I would like to pause handling items in the subscription until this task has completed (as the processing of the following items is dependent on the result) and then resume from the next item in the sequence without any loss.

**the next part is probably best read whilst looking at the Plunk [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/XPntV8/)**

To achieve this I have used a [buffer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-buffer) with a [swtichMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap). I thought these would do the job on their own but switchMap destroys and recreates the subscription the sequence gets reset every time.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    source$: Observable<any>;
    clearBuffer$ = new Subject();
    busy$ = new Subject();

    private itemSubscription: Subscription;
    private stayAliveSubscription: Subscription;

    items: any[] = [];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.source$ = Observable.range(1, 500).zip(
        Observable.interval(500),
        function (x, y) { return x; }
      ).share();

      this.busy$
        .subscribe(result => {
          if (!result) {
            this.clearBuffer$.next();
          }
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    start() {
      if (!this.itemSubscription) {
        this.itemSubscription =
          this.busy$.switchMap(busy => {
            if (busy) {
              return this.source$.buffer(this.clearBuffer$);
            } else {
              return this.source$;
            }
          })
            .subscribe(items => {
              if (Array.isArray(items)) {
                this.items.push('buffered: ' + items.join());
              } else {
                this.items.push('live feed: ' + items);
              }
            }, error => {
              this.items.push(error);
            });

        this.stayAliveSubscription = this.source$
          .subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);
          });

        this.busy$.next(false);
      }
   }
...
}
```

To fix this the **source$** observable is now shared and a separate subscription is started (**stayAliveSubscription**) so a single subscription is used throughout. This seems messy to me and I wanted to ask if anyone can show me better/alternative approaches to the problem.

I put the working sample in a Plunk [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/XPntV8/) click start to start the subscription and then set/unset the busy toggle to buffer and continue.

**edit: working code with concatMap**

I changed the [Plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/2DqP04/) to use concatMap. I've pasted the code below as well. The key is that the busy observable returned in concatMap must complete you can't just return the busy$ observable multiple times and call next on it when the busy status changes.

```js
    source$: Observable<any>;
    busy$ = new Subject();
    busy: boolean;

    private itemSubscription: Subscription;
    private stayAliveSubscription: Subscription;

    items: any[] = [];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.source$ = Observable.range(1, 500).zip(
        Observable.interval(500),
        function (x, y) { return x; }
      );

      this.busy$
        .subscribe(busy => {
          this.busy = <any>busy;
        });
    }

    start() {
      if (!this.itemSubscription) {
        this.itemSubscription = this.source$.concatMap(item => {
          const busySubject = new Subject();
          this.busy$
            .subscribe(result => {
              busySubject.next(item);
              busySubject.complete();
            });

          if (this.busy) {
            return busySubject;
          } else {
            return Observable.of(item);
          }

        })
          .subscribe(item => {
            this.items.push(item);
          }, error => {
            this.items.push(error);
          });
      }

      this.setBusy(false);
    }
```

Comment: what about [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but if it is just a matter of preserving the order of the emitted values while the "async task" can take a long (random) time, I guess you could use the `concatMap` operator.

### Theory

> #### [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap)
>
> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, in a serialized fashion waiting for each one to complete before merging the next.
>   [image: concatMap operator marble diagram]

### Practice

In this example, the `src`Observable emits a value every 100ms and each value is mapped to a new observable that emits a value between 0 and 2000ms (the async task). You can see the order is safe.

```js
let src = Rx.Observable.timer(0,100);
src.concatMap(i=>{
  return Rx.Observable.timer(Math.random()*2000).mapTo(i); // this is the async task
}).subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.4.0/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

### Making a hot Observable

You should also not use these subscriptions to make your observable emit data. Actually you should transform your [cold observable to a hot one](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html) using `.publish()`  and `.connect()` instead of `share()`and `subscribe()` :

```
this.source$ = Observable.range(1, 500).zip(
        Observable.interval(500),
        function (x, y) { return x; }
      ).publish();
// blah blah blah some code
this.source$.connect();
```

Comment: Thanks concatMap is working well for waiting on other observables, It took me a while to figure out the new observable must complete. I put it in a [Plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/9a9pUP/). I'm still working on using it with a single busy$ observable on the component.

Comment: so you want to avoid processing data when `busy$` emits `true` ? (I also added some notes about your `keepAliveSubscription` in my answer).

Comment: If busy emits true while you are already processing the data, should it cancel that job or not ?

Comment: thanks again I got concatMap working with the original Plunk as well https://embed.plnkr.co/2DqP04/. I will edit my question to add the final code.

Answer (score 1):

`delayWhen` is a very powerful operator. My solution uses `mergeMap` and `delayWhen`.

features: retry, throttle, pause, resume

1. Create and subscribe to Observable

```js
const concurrentLimit = 5
const retryLimit = 10
const source$ = from(new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => i))
// remove <boolean> if not typescript
const pause$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
const pass$ = pause$.pipe(filter((v) => !v));

const throttledTask$ = source$.pipe(
  mergeMap((item) => {
    return of(item).pipe(
      delayWhen(() => pass$),
      mergeMap(async (item) => {
         // you can also throw some errors
         return await new Promise((resolve)=>
             setTimeout(resolve(item), Math.random()*1000))
      }),
      retryWhen((errors$) => errors$.pipe(delay(1000), take(retryLimit)))
    );
  }, concurrentLimit)

const subscription = throttledTask$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

2. add Pause/Resume event handlers

```js
const pause = () => { pause$.next(true) }
const resume = () => { pause$.next(false) }
```

Explanation:

1. `delayWhen` will pause the stream and wait until the `pass$` signals emit.
2. `BehaviorSubject` is used to compose `pass$` signals, which will emit the last value when subscribed.
3. `mergeMap` can handle asynchronous tasks and has a concurrent thread count limit parameter. When `delayWhen` pauses a stream, that stream will remain inside `mergeMap` and occupies a concurrent 'thread'.
4. `retryWhen` will resubscribe until `errors$.pipe(delay(1000), take(retryLimit))` emits complete or error.