# How to make rxjs pause / resume?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

Now there is an array, the array value is the image link, for example:

```js
const imageList = [
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/16/20/29/new-york-4854718_960_720.jpg',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/14/16/04/mallorca-4848741_960_720.jpg',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/14/04/20/old-city-4847469_960_720.jpg',
  // more...
];
```

I want to use `rxjs` to download them sequentially(I’m an Electron app, so I can download it)

When the download of the first picture is completed, then download the second picture. When the third picture is being downloaded, the user clicks the pause button and waits for the download of the third picture to complete. Then no more downloads. When the user clicks the continue button, the download starts from the fourth picture.

I refer to this article: `Buffering (lossless)` section in https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd. The code in this article is:

```js
merge(
  source$.pipe( bufferToggle(off$, ()=>on$)  ),
  source$.pipe( windowToggle(on$, ()=>off$) )
).pipe(
  // then flatten buffer arrays and window Observables
  flatMap(x => x)
)
```

The demo URL is: https://thinkrx.io/gist/cef1572743cbf3f46105ec2ba56228cd

But there are two problems in this code, which do not meet my needs. I don't know how to modify it.

1. I use `redux-observable`, so I want to trigger them with two actions: (`this.props.start()` / `this.props.pause()`)
2. After recovery, data is still transferred one by one, not a one-time release

The current code looks like this:

```
export const epicDownloadResources = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<AnyAction>,
  store$: StateObservable<RootState>,
) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(appActions.other.start()),
    of([
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/16/20/29/new-york-4854718_960_720.jpg',
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/14/16/04/mallorca-4848741_960_720.jpg',
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/14/04/20/old-city-4847469_960_720.jpg',
    ]),
    mergeMap(() => {
      // code
    }),
    mergeMap((url: string) => {
      // downloading
    })
}
```

> In the real product, it will be downloading the company's internal picture resources, not other non-copyright pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a completely different approach.

If I understand correctly, you want to continue sequentially after the user has resumed. This actually means that it makes no sense to do windowing or buffering.

Some simple use of concatMap nesting should be enough in my opinion.

```
const pause$ = fromEvent(pauseButton, "click").pipe(
 mapTo(false),
);

const resume$ = fromEvent(resumeButton, "click").pipe(
 mapTo(true),
);

const pauseResume$ = merge(pause$,resume$).pipe(
 startWith(true),
 shareReplay(1),
)

const source = of(...imageList).pipe(
 concatMap((url, i) =>
   pauseResume$.pipe(
     tap(v => console.log(`should resume ${v}`)),
     filter(v => v), // Only resume if true
     take(1),
     concatMap(() =>
       from(fetch(url)).pipe(
         delay(1000), // Simulate slow request
         mapTo(i) // just for logging which request we just completed
       )
     )
   )
 )
);
source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

This will pause *starting a new request* until the resume$ has emitted a new value. I believe this is what you want based on your scenario.

I was not sure if you wanted the third request to complete in your scenario while the user has paused it. I assume you do, but if not, you can use another concatMap to pauseResume$ with filter after the request.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gvghhg?file=index.ts)

Comment: Great! This answer is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```js
const urlArr = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, idx) => 'url/' + idx);
let idx = 0;

const urlEmitter = new Subject();
const url$ = urlEmitter.asObservable();
const stopEmitter = new Subject();
const stopValues$ = stopEmitter.asObservable();

const start$ = fromEvent(start, 'click');
start$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => (stopEmitter.next(false), urlEmitter.next(urlArr[idx++]))); // Start emitting valeus

const stopSubscription = fromEvent(stop, 'click').pipe(mapTo(true)).subscribe(stopEmitter);

const shouldContinue$ = stopValues$.pipe(map(shouldStop => !shouldStop));

const subsequentStartClicks$ = start$.pipe(
  skip(1), // Skip the first time the `start` button is clicked
  observeOn(asyncScheduler), // Make sure it emits after the buffer has been initialized
  tap(() => stopEmitter.next(false)), // shouldContinue$ will emit `true`
);

const downloadedUrls$ = url$.pipe(
  mergeMap(url => of(url).pipe(delay(idx * 500))), // Simulate a file downloading
  combineLatest(shouldContinue$), // Make sure it acts according to `shouldContinue$`
  filter(([_, shouldContinue]) => shouldContinue),
  map(([v]) => v),
  tap((v) => console.warn(v)), // Debugging purposes...

  // Because of `combineLatest`
  // If you click `start` and wait some time, then you click `stop`
  // then you click again `start`, you might get the last value added to the array
  // this is because `shouldContinue$` emitted a new value
  // So you want to make sure you won't get the same value multiple times
  distinctUntilChanged(), 

  tap(() => urlEmitter.next(urlArr[idx++])),

  bufferToggle(
    start$,
    () => stopValues$.pipe(filter(v => !!v)),
  )
);

merge(
  subsequentStartClicks$.pipe(mapTo(false)), // Might not be interested in click events 
  downloadedUrls$
)
  .pipe(filter(v => !!v))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

I was inspired by [`bufferToggle`'s](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/bufferToggle) diagram.

My idea was to follow the same approach, with the exception that values should be emitted only when the `start$` stream emitted and should stop when `stop$` did.

```
----X--X----------------------------------> urls$

-Y----------------------------------------> start$

-----------Z------------------------------> end$


-----------[X, X]-------------------------------> urls$
```

Every time the `stop` button is pressed, a `true` value is pushed into the `stopValues$` stream. `shouldContinue$` determines whether the `url$` stream should keep on pushing values or not, depending on `stopValues$`.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pjcuk3?file=index.ts).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I tried your example. Found some minor problems, sometimes data loss

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I’ll have a look in a few hours.

Comment: @Black-Hole as a quick fix, you could decrement the ‘idx’ when the stop button is pressed

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried it, it should be a problem of my ability, in the end, no modification was successful

Comment: @Black-Hole, I've updated my answer. It should be working fine now!

Comment: Hi Andrei Gătej, thank you very much for taking the time to answer. But currently, @boyen 's answer is exactly what I need. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Hi @Black-Hole! Don't worry, I've learnt a lot trying to solve this :), glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Pausing and resuming an observable stream, please suggest better options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388032/pausing-and-resuming-an-observable-stream-please-suggest-better-options/64220250#64220250)

> `delayWhen` is a very powerful operator. My solution uses `mergeMap`
> and `delayWhen`.
>
> features: retry, throttle, pause, resume
>
> 1. Create and subscribe to Observable

```js
const concurrentLimit = 5
const retryLimit = 10
const source$ = from(new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => i))
// remove <boolean> if not typescript
const pause$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
const pass$ = pause$.pipe(filter((v) => !v));

const throttledTask$ = source$.pipe(
  mergeMap((item) => {
    return of(item).pipe(
      delayWhen(() => pass$),
      mergeMap(async (item) => {
         // you can also throw some errors
         return await new Promise((resolve)=>
             setTimeout(resolve(item), Math.random()*1000))
      }),
      retryWhen((errors$) => errors$.pipe(delay(1000), take(retryLimit)))
    );
  }, concurrentLimit)

const subscription = throttledTask$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

> 2. add Pause/Resume event handlers

```js
const pause = () => { pause$.next(true) }
const resume = () => { pause$.next(false) }
```

> Explanation:
>
> 1. `delayWhen` will pause the stream and wait until the `pass$` signals emit.
> 2. `BehaviorSubject` is used to compose `pass$` signals, which will emit the last value when subscribed.
> 3. `mergeMap` can handle asynchronous tasks and has a concurrent thread count limit parameter. When `delayWhen` pauses a stream, that
>    stream will remain inside `mergeMap` and occupies a concurrent
>    'thread'.
> 4. `retryWhen` will resubscribe until `errors$.pipe(delay(1000), take(retryLimit))` emits complete or error.